# Rails - Modules Without Includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a lot of fun with modules that dynamically add methods onto my Ruby classes.

I'm bringing these into my classes using the include syntax and everything is working as expected.

However, I notice that when I use gems such as Authlogic or Paperclip, the explicit import is not needed.  I can simply issue a acts_as_authentic or a has_attached_file on my ActiveRecord derived models and the class methods are automatically in scope and called to decorate my class.

What's going on here?  Is inclusion in the Gemfile putting all of the class methods implicitly in scope?

I would like to write a Gem to behave in the same way.

Edit - This post http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/ suggests that ActiveRecord::Base is being enhanced with the include.  Is this what's happening?

Answer (score 3):

The best answer is the code itself.

Rails plugins normally use [`Rails::Railtie`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html) (here's the [Paperclip example](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/v3.1.2/lib/paperclip.rb#L54)) to add functionalities to Rails.

As you can see from the [`Paperclip::Railtie`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/v3.1.2/lib/paperclip/railtie.rb) file, Paperclip extends `ActiveRecord::Base` including some custom modules. In this case, [`Paperclip::Glue`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/v3.1.2/lib/paperclip/glue.rb) is the one that provides the `has_attached_file` macro, along with several other methods.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, Paperclip::Glue)
```

Comment: Is this code required to load the paperclip libraries, I'm pretty sure it just need included in the gemfile for paperclip methods to be available in the MVC.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, you don't need to do this manually. When you require the gem, this is done for you. The user asked for an explanation of what's going on, and here's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the gem is required in the application's gemfile, Rails 3 will load all dependencies when the app starts.